# How can I load an image from drawable folder?

Tags: android, drawable

I've the file name of an image stored in the drawable? how can I open it? I want to know the path?

the file name is `String imageFileName = "image.png"`

and I want to have the path string something like file://drawable/image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open it using [openRawResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29). See more at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html).

See [this post](http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html) regarding how to construct a uri to raw resource, though as far as I know it is not recommended.

Comment: See my edits in the original post. I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: As I wrote, although it is not recommended, the post in the last link I gave shows exactly that.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can access it through its resource ID. See previous answers such as this one: 
[Select Drawable file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159793/select-drawable-file-path)

Comment: See my edits in the original post. I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code segment showing how you can refer to an image through its resource ID.

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
   R.drawable.pic1);
int pic_width  = mBitmap.width();
int pic_height = mBitmap.height();
```

[See here for more detail](http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/3748281)

Comment: See my edits in the original post. I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough.